# c# Process Start launch the desired application but that application doesn't work well

Tags: c#, process.start

I have a program where I can launch multiple games. I have one game that creates a json file with the player progress, the problem is that when I open this game manually (from windows) the json file is created correctly and the game works well, but when I open the same game from my application, the game is executed, but doesn't work well because the json file is never created and when I try to read another json I created previously the game can't read them.
I checked if the gamepath was wrong in my program, but it isn't.
I read some other posts about process.start, the only one I've seen useful is about process impersonation, but I don't know how to use it or for what do you use it. I think my problem is about lack of permissions.

This is my code where I launch my games:

```
string downloadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),
            "Outlands Adventure Client");               
string gamePath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, currentGameInfo.GameName, currentGameInfo.GameName + ".exe");
MessageBox.Show(gamePath);
Process.Start(gamePath);
```

And this is gamePath that my messagebox shows:

[image: And this is gamePath that my messagebox shows]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set work dir with game directory like:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =  <...>;
process.StartInfo.FileName = <...>;
process.Start();
```

Comment: by game directory you mean the path where is my game? like this: C:\Users\thena\Outlands Adventure Client\Outlands Adventure (Alpha) - Fixed Resolution

Comment: @Napo:yes543210

Comment: Since you already have the full path to the `.exe` in `gamePath`, I'd use [GetDirectoryName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetDirectoryName_System_String_) to set the `.WorkingDirectory` like this: `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(gamePath);`

Comment: @aepot okey, didn't know that